# Как загружаемому файлу передать свое имя не изменяя сам файл и скачать этот файл

Tags: php, yii2

Прописал код

```
     public function actionCreate()
 {
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $model = new Product();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $documentName=$model->id;
            $model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            $model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$documentName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            $model->document='uploads/'.$documentName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        $this->redirect('/site/index');
    }
}
```

Он работает, но вот только имя переименовывается в            $documentName=$model->id; , оно и понятно почему, вот вопрос как передать имя исходного файла, и как потом её скачать.

Попытался сделать так

```
  <p><a href="<?= $product->document?>" download>Скачать файл</a>
```

Но выдает ошибку файлы отсутсвуют.

Comment: `<p><a href="<?=$documentFile?>" download="<?=$documentTitle?>">Скачать файл</a>`, где `$documentFile` - это сам файл, существующий физически на хостинге, а `$documentTitle` - это любое название **скачиваемого** файла, хоть на русском.

Comment: допустим я загрузил файл qwerty.txt, при попадании на сервер он уже переименуется в id строки.txt, но я хочу оставить имя файла qwerty.txt что мне надо прописать в  $documentName=$model->???, а вот насчет загрузки download="<?=$documentTitle?> особо ничего не решает

Comment: Попробуйте тогда использовать `$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');` и посмотреть что будет находиться в модели сразу после этой строки `var_dump($model->file);`. Под рукой Yii нет, но API говорит вроде что там должна быть вся инфа по загружаемому файлу.

Comment: null, а вот debugger= Call to a member function saveAs() on null

Comment: А что содержит `UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file')` до сохранения?

Comment: public function actionCreate()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $model = new Product();
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $documentName=$model->id;
                $model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');

Comment: загрузить пытаюсь файл в виде txt

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду что если вывести его? `var_dump(UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file'));`

Comment: object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#224 (5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "composer.txt" ["tempName"]=> string(39) "C:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\php3D6E.tmp" ["type"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["size"]=> int(30) ["error"]=> int(0) }

Comment: `$fileInfo=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file'); $originalName=$fileInfo->name` = composer.txt. Не оно разве?

Comment: да но в таблице composer  отпадает а передается уже .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из переписки с автором вопроса:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $model = new Product();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            $model->file->saveAs( '/uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            $model->document='/uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        $this->redirect('/site/index');
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Если модель не сохраняет оригинальное имя файла в БД (я это так понял из последнего комментария), то скиньте еще и модель.

Comment: да все класс работает, но почему при загрузке точнее при скачивании файла выдает "Ошибка: Файлы отсутствуют". Я использую <p><a href="<?= $product->document?>" download>Скачать файл</a> для скачивание

Comment: @WorkerTestovich а чему равен `$product->document`?

Comment: <?php var_dump($product->document)?> = string(25) "uploads/composer.txt"

Comment: @WorkerTestovich попробуйте перед `uploads` добавить `/`. Пути на сайте должны быть относительными корня сайта.

Comment: @WorkerTestovich обновил ответ

Comment: простите а куда именно добавить что-то я не совсем понял

Comment: я добавил / в контроллере перед uploads но результатов прогресса не имею

Comment: или же для скачивания нужен отдельный action?

Comment: @WorkerTestovich action отдельный не нужен, достаточно просто ссылки на файл и атрибута download. Вы уверены, что файл composer.txt физически существует в папке uploads?

Comment: да при загрузке файл сохраняется в базе mysql-uploads/composer.txt и в папке uploads-composer.txt

Comment: @WorkerTestovich можете где нибудь выложить скриншот исходного кода страницы с тем местом, где у вас прописана ссылка? А также скриншот самого файла в папке uploads? Может вы что-то напутали?

Comment: <tr>
    <td><?= Yii::t('app', 'Service Standart')?></td>
    <td class="single_passport">
    <p><a href="<?= $product->document?>"download>Скачать 
    файл</a (*.docx, 25,56 kB) </td>
</tr>

Comment: @WorkerTestovich мне именно скриншот нужен или хотя бы сгенерированный браузером html-код, без php))

Comment: https://ibb.co/gkagxw вот скрин страницы с ссылкой

Comment: @WorkerTestovich добавьте точку перед `/uploads`, должно так получиться - `./uploads` (если я ничего не напутал). Вам нужен путь, относительно корня сайта, а не `ru/category/`